# Data Conversion Task Fails with Unspecified Error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have an SSIS package in which data is loaded from delimited file to SQL table.

The job fails with the following message and it happens intermittently once or twice a month.

> Error: Component "Conversions, clsid {62B1106C-7DB8-4EC8-ADD6-4C664DFFC54A}" could not be created
>       and returned error code 0x80004005 "Unspecified error". Make sure that the
>       component is registered correctly

Conversions is the name of the task

> Error: There were errors during task validation.

If I run the job again, it completes successfully.

Could someone please help me to resolve this issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: 1. Set delay validation to true. 2. Chances are your component is corrupt. Repair should solve it. For more, put up the code and screenshot of packages.

Comment: @user55449 I didn't get what you meant to add code

Comment: @PrabhatG Set delay validation is already set to true. If the component is corrupt then I think it wont be able to run in the subsequent try

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e74dc9a7-a894-4ab1-91dd-22beabd18846/data-conversion-task-failed?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Answer (score 0):

From the link below you can check the following:

1. Check the All Execution Reports of the package and click all messages to find more information when the error occurs.
2. Check the SQL error log which by default are located at Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.n\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG and ERRORLOG.n files, see if there's anything happened during or before the agent job.
3. Search the  clsid {62B1106C-7DB8-4EC8-ADD6-4C664DFFC54A} in registry editor and check Component Services (start-Administrative Tools ->Components Services->Computers->my computer->DCOM Config), located the app and check properties->security, add NetWORK Service account and give it the launch and activate permissions.

**Reference**

- [Data Conversion Task Failed](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e74dc9a7-a894-4ab1-91dd-22beabd18846/data-conversion-task-failed?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Comment: Thank you ..Log folder is missing in the path  Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.n\MSSQL and 3rd point is not clear. I could find clsid in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->Software->Wow6432Node->Classes->CLSID   , not in Administrative Tools ->Components Services->Computers->my computer->DCOM Config.    Please suggest solution.